# Запрос по сортировке по текущему дню

Tags: mysql, select, запрос

есть вот такая структура,

```
id|date
1 |2015-05-26
2 |2015-05-27
.............
```

не могу понять, как сделать сортировку по дате, чтоб выводило в начале списка по текущему дню, а потом остальные записи

Comment: А у вас есть даты и больше и меньше текущей?

Comment: @Batanichek, да. и в этом то и проблема. даты разные могуть быть. Хоть 2026 г )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table
 order by if(`date`=current_date(),0,1), `date`
```

Comment: попробую, результат напишу.

Comment: очень интересно вы написали

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно сделать через union all

например ка кто так

```
select id,date from table where date=Current_date()
union all 
select id,date from table where date<>Current_date()
```

## Update

С учетом комментариев @Mike

можно сделать такой вариант

```
select id,date from (
select id,date, 1 as ord from table where date=Current_date()
    union all 
    select id,date,2 as ord from table where date<>Current_date() or date is null) 
order by ord
```

Но вариант @Mike красивее

Comment: так явно нельзя. порядок записей без указания order by не определен. а order будет действовать на все выражение

Comment: @Mike Не много не понял,  почему не определен сначала date=Current_date() потом все остальное .. или я что то не так понимаю?

Comment: Оптимизатор увидев ваши = и <> запросто может оптимизировать запрос на одну выборку из всей таблицы убрав union. Порядок записей на выходе _не обязан_ соответствовать порядку выборок union. оптимизатор выполняет запросы в том порядке, в каком сочтет нужным. Пока нет явно указанного order by для всего запроса SQL не гарантирует никакой порядок.

Comment: И еще ваш запрос теряет записи у которых date is NULL

Comment: @Mike на счет порядка не знал . так во всех sql или только в my?

Comment: В принципе во всех, хотя сейчас проверяю, на таком простом запросе оптимизатор MySQL делает как написано. Проблема в том, что по стандартам SQL он это делать не обязан. Другая версия может оказаться умнее или глупее (это как посмотреть) и выдать например наоборот

Comment: Самое интересное, что если не сказать 'all' то MySQL продолжает соблюдать порядок. А Oracle порядок нарушает. Видать разные алгоритмы сверки дублей. Но уже на лицо зависимость результата от внутреннего алгоритма работы БД

Comment: @Mike если без all то oracle сортирует http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/tuning/ctuntransform14044.html , думал что без all не будет сортировтаь, спасибо за инфо